# make is not recognize as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundle

I am using Windows-7. I installed **Ruby 1.9.3p327** and **Rails 3.2.9**.

Now, I create a project then run command in command prompt `"rails install json -v 1.7.7"` but get error below

```
make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What is make and how to resolve it.

thanks

Comment: For a Rails dev environment, I suggest using a virtual machine running linux. It will be much less pain.

Comment: Also don't use Rails 3.2.9 -- there's a couple of serious security issues with it. Update to the latest in the 3.2.x series.

Comment: Thanks..but i have no linux system.. so please give me solutions for windows...now i am update Rails version...any other thinks...?

Comment: If you really want to use windows, you probably want DevKit from rubyinstaller.org, which I'm pretty sure includes make.

Comment: But you can easily run a VM on your windows box. All you need is VMWare Player and an Ubuntu ISO -- both of which are free. I can _guarantee_ that it will be less pain for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use vagrant (http://vagrantup.com), This will allow you to use a linux vm for running the app and you can do all the developing in windows.